# I want to fetch the details from payload tab of developers tool

Tags: javascript, python, automation, scrapy

I want to fetch the details of url which differ from ones which are present in the anchor tab. Accessing the href link directs to previous page rather than next page.
How do I fetch the following view source value from payload:
[image: Payload details]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Using requests:

```py
import requests

url = "YOUR URL"

params = {
    "doc_id": "2384416",
    "request_token": ...
    ...
}

r = requests.post(url, params=params)
           # ^^^^ PUT, PATCH etc.
```

Install requests if you don't have it:

```bash
pip3 install requests
```

Comment: I don't want to send this values from my code. I need to use them in my code that is fetch them from that payload tab. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, this would be handled by a browser, maybe you should use selenium or something similar.